# How to loop through a directory, get all file names, then get the contents of those files in Java

Tags: java, file, exception

So in C drive, I have a folder called `Search Files` and inside `Search Files`, I have four subdirectories called `Folder 1`, `Folder 2`, `Folder 3`, and `Folder 4`.

Inside of `Folder 1`, I have a text file called `hello.txt` and the contents of that file is `hello`.

My expected output is `"Directory of the file" + "file name" + "file body"`.

Below is the code that I have right now.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class FileDirectories {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File[] files = new File("C:\\Search Files").listFiles();
        showFiles(files);
    }

    public static void showFiles(File[] files) throws IOException {
        String line = null;
        
            try{
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        String fileName = "Directory" + file.getName();
                        //System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                        while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        in.close();
                        showFiles(file.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName() + file.toString());
                    }
                }
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
        
        
        
        /*Iterator<File> it = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File("C://Search Files//"), null, false);
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(((File) it.next()).getName());
        }*/
    }
}
```

When I execute the above code, I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Search   Files\Folder 1 (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:72)
        at org.raghav.stuff.FileDirectories.showFiles(FileDirectories.java:27)
        at org.raghav.stuff.FileDirectories.main(FileDirectories.java:16)
```

Once again, I need to get the file directory, the file name, and the contents of the file.

In case of the `hello.txt`, the expected output should be:
**C:\Search Files\Folder1\   hello.txt   hello**

Can you guys point me in the right directions? How to fix the above exception and how do I get a String that displays the directory, file name, and the contents of the file?

Comment: Your reading code is in the `if (file.isDirectory()) {` block - you are trying to read directories

Comment: How would you fix it though?

Comment: Well, don't do it, obviously :) You have an `else` clause for files there, that's where you should use the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks okay except you have to organized it as follows especially showFiles method.

```
public static void showFiles(File[] files) throws IOException {
    String line = null;

    try{
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String fileName = "Directory: " + file.getName();
                System.out.print(fileName);
                showFiles(file.listFiles()); // Calls same method again.
            } else {
                System.out.print("\tFile: " + file.getName() + file.toString());
                //System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.print("\t Content:" + line);
                }
                in.close();
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the output will look like:

```
Directory: Folder 1 File: C:\Search Files\Folder 1\test.txt  Content:this is a test
Directory: Folder 2 File: C:\Search Files\Folder 2\test.txt  Content:this is a test
Directory: Folder 3 File: C:\Search Files\Folder 3\test.txt  Content:this is a test
Directory: Folder 4 File: C:\Search Files\Folder 4\test.txt  Content:this is a test
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation also? What did you change and why?

Comment: Sure. I moved the code to read a file in the else section of if(file.isDirectory()) because if it is a directory then you want to make a recursive call to the showFiles() method again else print the content.